# Bounty handling: Reward existing answer

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I think that it doesn't make any sense to force me to wait three days until I can reward an existing answer. I totally see the sense of this regulation for the other cases.

This is especially bad as it may reduce the number of cases in which this happens. Now I have to remember for two days that I wanted to give a bounty instead of just throwing some rep at the answer.

Furthermore IMHO it doesn't make sense to show these questions in the bounty list. You even have to open them to see that the bounty has effectively already been awarded (just not technically yet).

Comment: See [Should the 24-hour timeout apply to bounties awarded for “exemplary answer”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116072/should-the-24-hour-timeout-apply-to-bounties-awarded-for-exemplary-answer) and [I want to award a bounty to an existing answer; should I have to wait 24 hours?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107282/i-want-to-award-a-bounty-to-an-existing-answer-should-i-have-to-wait-24-hours)

Comment: It's only one day, not three. And you get reminders.

Comment: @Gilles Depends on how old the question is. If the question is two days old then you can create the bounty at once and have to wait for 24 hours to assign it.